# How do I determine if a sample size is too small?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I am using the public dataset from Divvy, a Chicago bikeshare company. The dataset of rides contains among other things location, time, ride length, and whether the ride was taken by someone with a Divvy membership or not. I am comparing member and casual behavior.

Plotting the ride length of members and casuals in a density graph produces a peak, the corresponding x value of ride length is compared, and the difference in minutes graphed using ggplot.

[image]

As you can see, the results for the Ev_nocollege cluster look strange, and this behavior shows in other graphs of the dataset. It is the smallest cluster, being 7586 observations compared to the whole of 5051784 rows. Below is the count of each segment of the Ev_nocollege used in the graph.

[image]

Are the counts of each segment too low in some cases for the data to be relied upon? What test would I use to determine the relative reliability of the segments, taking the counts of each into account? I need to explain the strange behavior of that segment somehow.

Comment: Many people do statistics with only tens of observations.

Comment: @Forgotten Many more do it with *no* observations ;-).

Answer (score 2):

To determine if your data are too small, you would need to perform a power calculation.  You're free to search this forum for power calculation questions similar to your own but beware [testing the hypothesis suggested by the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data) is a statistical fallacy.